# Microsoft Ace - Keep Getting Require Title Preference Set to True - Even If It Is

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, ace-plugin

I've copied the https://github.com/Microsoft/ace/tree/master/examples/WithOtherPlugins/InAppBrowser code, but when I run it on android I get the error of requiring ShowTitle preference as set to true, which is set.  I have tried taking out all references to titles and still get the same error.  I saw another help request with the same problem, but no solution was provided: [Use Ace Plugin to Make iOS/Android TabBar & TableView using Platform Specific Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689252/use-ace-plugin-to-make-ios-android-tabbar-tableview-using-platform-specific-ja)